# Symbian C++: TBuf Question

Tags: c++, symbian, descriptor

I have a TBuf variable in my code that looks as follows:

```
TBuf<100> test;
test.Copy( _L("02somestringofrandomlength"));
```

What I would like to do now, is to ignore the number (which takes the first two characters).
Is there a nice way to extract the variable-length string from the test variable and thereby dismissing the number at the beginning?

many thanks

Answer (score 4):

Assuming it's always exactly the first 2 characters and the input length is greater than 2:

```
TPtrC tail = test.Mid(2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
TDes::Right()
```

For example:

```
TPtrC right = test.Right( test.Length() - 2 );
```

Answer (score -1):

Why first copy the string and then chop it, if you can copy just the part you need?

```
test.Copy( _L("02somestringofrandomlength") + 2 );
```

Comment: When downvoting, please tell me why.  This code works, and does what was asked for.